# Segmentation fault error. I am trying to parse the Payload and extract the value and return the value. What mistake i am doing?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The msg contains a payload, in the form |tag|length|value|
size of tag and length is of 2 bytes. size of value is described inside length, 
and the data type can be uint16, uint32 or uint8.

```
typedef struct
{
  response_uint16_t msg[5];
}payload;

void func(response_uint16_t *msg, int type)  
{
  int *posPtr = NULL;
  void *temp;
  int valueLen = msg->length;
  posPtr = &msg->tag;
  posPtr += sizeof(msg->tag);
  posPtr += sizeof(msg->length);
  posPtr++;                         //ideally this should now point to value.
  if(type == 1)
  {
    memcpy((U8*)temp, *posPtr, valueLen);
    return(*temp);
  }
  if(type == 2)
  { 
    memcpy((U16*)temp, *posPtr, valueLen);
    return(*temp);
  }
}

int main()
{
  payload *P;
  p = (struct payload*)malloc(sizeof(p));
  int res;
  /*assumne the msg is filled here and value expected to be filled here is of type U16 */
  res =(U16)func(&p->msg[1], 2); 
  res =(U8)func(&p->msg[2], 1);
.
.

}
```

Comment: Can you first update your code to compile without warning, it will help you discover the problems

Comment: `void * memcpy(void *to, const void *from, size_t numBytes);`.  You're copying *to* `temp`, but you never assign `temp` any storage.  Undefined behavior.

Comment: if i take void temp;
....
memcpy((U16)temp, *posPtr, valueLen);

then it throws an  error variable or filed is void here!!
i need to assign a storage type based on the type, if it is 1 then it should be uint 8 so on

Comment: please provide [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Code has multiple compilation warnings and errors. `void func(response_uint16_t *msg, int type) ` function returning values??

Comment: `posPtr += sizeof(msg->tag);` is incrementing the pointer by `msg->tag` multipled by `sizeof(uint16_t)` bytes. What exactly is the packet structure?

Comment: posPtr   = &msg->tag                           //pointing to x001 tag           
posPtr += sizeof(msg->tag)                //pointing to x002 length 
posPtr +=sizeof(msg->length)            //pointing to x004 value
posPtr++;                                            // posPtr should point to the value

Since i dont know the how big the the value is,
With the help of valueLen i need to read till that much and store it in temo and return the same.

Comment: `posPtr` is `int*`. You are incrementing by `sizeof(int)` multiplied by the value. I am sorry, in my last comment I assumed it's `uint16_t*`. Please read about pointer arithmetic in C. Please edit your question to specify additional information. Please post the `response_uint16_t` type definition. Please post a compilable [MCVE] others can test. Please specify resulting value you want to get. Please post `U16` and `U8` types definitions. Note, `memcpy(..., *posPtr, ...)` is copying from the derefenced pointer value, I doubt there is a valid address there.

Comment: ok i post the compilable one

Comment: what is the definition of `response_uint16_t`?

Comment: regarding: `memcpy((U8*)temp, *posPtr, valueLen);` and similar statements.  There is no need to cast the parameters AND the function is expecting a `void*` for the first parameter

Comment: the posted code does not compile! Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues inside this code snippet:

1. As @Tibrogargan commented, `temp` pointer is accessed (copied-to) before being initialized;
2. Pointer `posPtr` is declared as `int *`, but it seems to be advanced by bytes.

```
  posPtr = &msg->tag;            // <== pointing to `tag`
  posPtr += sizeof(msg->tag);    // <== pointing to element after `tag`, i.e. `length`? NO! Advanced for two integers width since size of (msg->tag) should be 2 as you said
  posPtr += sizeof(msg->length); // <== pointing to element after `length`, i.e. `value`? NO! Same reason
```

Assuming your platform integer is 32-bit wide. And you said "size of tag and length is of 2 bytes". So `posPtr += sizeof(msg->tag)` is in fact `posPtr += 2`. Same case for `posPtr += sizeof(msg->length)`.

```
initial posPtr --> +----------------------------+
                   | tag    | __two_bytes_pad__ |
      posPtr+1 --> +----------------------------+
                   | length | __two_bytes_pad__ |
      posPtr+2 --> +----------------------------+
                   | value                      |
                   +----------------------------+
```

Again, even without above issue, the comment in following line looks false. `posPtr` looks should pointing to next element after `value`. Anyhow, without knowing your actual data structure, I cannot say exactly where `posPtr` is pointing to. But this line worth double checking.

```
posPtr++;                         //ideally this should now point to value.
```

3. You are assuming the struct is packed but which is normally not, if not specified when define the struct, see [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing) for more details.
4. Pointer `temp` is declared as `void *` therefore cannot be directly de-referenced.
5. Return type of `func` is `void` therefore cannot return any value.
6. You might be assuming the endianness when trying to access the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for variable `temp` using `malloc` or `calloc` like this:

```
  int valueLen = msg->length;
  size_t valueSize = type ==1 ? sizeof(U8) : sizeof(U16);
  void *temp = malloc(valueLen * valueSize);
```

Then perform memcopy so as to avoid `Undefined behaviour` caused by copying something to `temp` variable, which often but not always results in Seg Fault as pointed by @Tibrogargan